# Using Increments in For loops

Tags: c, for-loop

I encountered the below question in a C test:

**Do the following two programs have the same output:**

**Program 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float p[3][2];

    int j=0;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("Enter x%d y%d :", i+1, i+1);
        scanf("%f %f", &p[i][j], &p[i][++j]);
        j=0;
    }

    printf("%f %f\n", p[0][0], p[0][1]);
    printf("%f %f\n", p[1][0], p[1][1]);
    printf("%f %f", p[2][0], p[2][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Program 2:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float p[3][2];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("Enter x%d y%d :", i+1, i+1);
        scanf("%f %f", &p[i][0], &p[i][1]);
    }

    printf("%f %f\n", p[0][0], p[0][1]);
    printf("%f %f\n", p[1][0], p[1][1]);
    printf("%f %f", p[2][0], p[2][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

While writing the test, for obvious reason I reasoned that, ***In runtime `j` and `j++` (line 10 program 1) will get replaced by 0 and 1***, So both programs will have the same output. But when I checked it in my computer output for both programs was as follows:

Output of Program 1:

```
Enter x1 y1 :1 1
Enter x2 y2 :3 2
Enter x3 y3 :4 1
-0.000000 1.000000
-0.000000 2.000000
0.000000 1.000000
```

Output of Program 2:

```
Enter x1 y1 :1 1
Enter x2 y2 :3 2
Enter x3 y3 :4 1
1.000000 1.000000
3.000000 2.000000
4.000000 1.000000
```

I think, in **program 1** the values for p[0][0], p[1][0], p[2][0] are garbage values. I want to know why p[0][0], p[1][0], p[2][0] did'nt received the input values 1, 3, 4 respectively.

Comment: `scanf("%f %f", &p[i][j], &p[i][++j]);` attempts to both use **and** update `j` in the same expression (without an intervening *sequence point*). This is **UB** (Undefined Behaviour)

Comment: The first one is undefined behavior. You don't know which of the expressions `j` or `++j` will be evaluated first.

Comment: i dont know the concept of UB please elaborate

Comment: @HAL9000 it's not so much the expressions themselves but rather the order in which `j` (reading `j`) and the side-effect of `++j` (updating `j`).

Comment: UB: http://wiki.c2.com/?UndefinedBehavior and many other google hits

Comment: @pmg, I know there is more going on than the order of evaluation, the read an update may not even be atomic. But there is not need add to the confusion by explaining everything that can go wrong.

Comment: See also [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/15168)

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you first increment the value of `j` and than read it when you use `++j`. However if you use `j++` you will first read the value and then increment it and the program should work. So the `scanf` line would look as follow:

```
scanf("%f %f", &p[i][j], &p[i][j++]);
```

But be *CAREFUL* because I don't think that this is consider as good practice and even the compiler throws a warning.

```
warning: operation on ‘j’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
         scanf("%f %f", &p[i][j], &p[i][j++]);
                                        ~^~
```

Comment: `++j` is not specified to increment `j` and then read it, nor is `j++` specified to read `j` and then increment it. Rather, `++j` evaluates to `j+1` and as a **side effect** increments `j`. The actual increment may occur before, during, or after the evaluation. Similarly, `j++` evaluates to `j` and as a side effect increments `j`.

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit dubious; your 'however' sentence is just wrong, though.  The compiler correctly gives a warning (though you should be using `-Werror` so it becomes an error) — and it would give the same warning on the code in the question.